# Facing issue in Shopping Cart in java using jsp and servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am creating a Shopping cart in which I have created a product page with setters and getter's. Then I created a Helper Class using addtocart method then created a class AddProduct where i have written doPost method now i need to fetch shopping cart details on my jsp which is cart.jsp. I m facing problem to fetch on products which were added to cart...

Links added here..
 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By64gw5ORtRjQW44MFpZT3hPOW8&authuser=0

Comment: Other Important links are added here link AddProduct Page and cart.jsp(https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By64gw5ORtRjM1Axekc2TFVscUU&authuser=0)  && (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By64gw5ORtRjOWFMNWRrVWo2Ums&authuser=0)

Comment: Can you provide the details sample code and error details you are facing?

Comment: Questions should not include links to code on other places, especially places that are "volatile".  For example, if you decide to "clean out" your google drive, nobody else will be able to understand what your question means.

Comment: @Ranjitsinh I m not able to create cart,jsp page as i want to display products which as being added in cart by user as i m beginner in JSP so i don't know how to display those products in JSP...

Comment: @StephenC Yes u r rite but i don't have privilege to add code in my answer so i had no choice other then doing this way...

Comment: You can add code to your question.  What you can't do is add images.